# How to fix ripped out ball joint in indirect under seat steering recumbent

Tags: fork, handlebars, recumbent, steering

There are two ball joints involved in the steering mechanism of my under seat steering recumbent.

One of them ripped out of its socket:

[image: Picture of broken part.]

The dirty grey-green part inside the end of the bar is made of rubber and is supposed to hold the steel ball on the handlebar. The rubber part has the number "010-0000-017-008" on top and "12" on the bottom. The metal piece surrounding it has an "R" stamped in. According to a comment the same part is used for the self-leveling suspension adjustment of Mercedes 1999 E320.

Here you can see the intact mechanism:

[image: More zoomed out picture.]

And here an overview with the whole bike visible, just for better illustration of why that problem is even bicycle related. :)

[image: Even more zoomed out picture.]

I tried pushing it back on by hand, then using pliers but in vain. Possibly there are larger pliers which can apply more force, but I already applied quite a lot.

Just for the curious, how this happened: The part where the ball joint fastens to the handlebar can be moved along the handlebar. I moved it out, this means that small movements of the handlebar result in much larger movements of the fork, so the steering is more responsive and smaller curves are possible before the handlebar hits the thighs. This also means that there is nothing preventing the fork from turning more than 90 degrees especially when no thighs are preventing the handlebar from turning, for example when pushing the bicycle by the seat. That's what happened, the fork turned so much that because of the steering axis angle pushing forward resulted in a force turning the wheel even more, until the ball joint snapped and the front wheel pointed backwards.

Comment: Have you checked with the supplier?  They may have relevant advice about a repair or replacement

Comment: Another thought - to stop this happening again you might want to fit a "steering damper" which is a spring to keep the fork pointing forward.  Its weak enough that turning is unaffected, but enough to stop the front wheel flopping over when unloaded.  Shopping bikes and cargo bikes might use them.  Check  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/

Comment: @Criggie I have, but they didn't respond on Friday and don't work Saturday, so I thought maybe someone here could help me first. :) The steering damper is a good idea, if I find a way to mount one (or maybe ask the manufacturer too) I will.

Comment: I have a  length of cord hanked up on/in some of my bikes.  Handy for tying down loads, but I once used it as reins, tied at the bars and the middle held in my hand at the saddle.  Made walking a lot nicer.   Or just ride and don't walk :)

Comment: I've thought about it and had the perfect idea for preventing this in the future: The part connecting the fork and the push rod has a slit. I'm going to put a screw in that slit which sticks out a couple of cm on top and put some rubber or shrink wrap around it. Then that screw will hit the frame before the fork can turn 90 degrees in either direction. There will be little force on either the screw or the ball joints because that only develops at angles greater than 90 degrees.

Comment: I talked with a guy from the manufacturer on the phone. Apparently it's hard but possible to put them back together, but quality would suffer. He thinks the reason it ripped out could be that the attachment ring in the handlebar is slightly turned, the screw bearing the ball should have a right angle with the rod. I'll put in in an answer once I've received the replacement and fixed it. Maybe also try assembling the old one again.

Comment: First off, you need to use some lubrication if trying to "force" the rubber part back on.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Oh, right, I could have added some. Although there was still some there because it was properly lubricated before it ripped apart.

Comment: Oh my goodness... This is the exact plug in my Mercedes 1999 E320 wagon.  That's how I found this thread.  It's used for the self-leveling suspension adjustment.  Mine has ripped out due to deterioration.

Comment: @GuitarPicker Thanks, if I ever need another one the info might make it possible to get one locally instead of having it shipped from the bike manufacturer in the Netherlands.

Comment: They don't list just the sockets in the Mercedes catalog.  The whole assembly costs about $50 USD and has two of these in it I think.  I ended up filling the missing grommets with a hot glue gun last night, but my application should be under less stress than yours.

Comment: If the part is used in a car, most likely its used in several other cars and may be fabricated by several makers, so there must be generic and off brands available at many auto parts stores. I do not know how is this market in you country, but in mine, off-brand spares are so common, that you only need to take the broken one to the store and the salesperson is usually able to find a suitable replacement. This can be more affordable than a Mercedes original part. OEM parts are sometimes cheaper when not sold thru the official dealer.

Comment: @Jahaziel Thank you, that's actually a good tip if it breaks again and I need another replacement. I have never owned a car so I don't know the market in my country either, but it would be worth a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible but hard to **put it back together**: Use *lots* of force and push the sleeve straight onto the ball.

- Put it on loosely.
- Add some lubricant if necessary. Some is probably already there.
- If you've got sufficiently large pliers, wrap a cloth around the
  parts to protect them from scratches and push them together.
- If using your hands, wrap a cloth around the parts lots of times to cushion them and increase the size of the area you are pressing against. It's probably fine to just press on top, but I tried opposing the force from the bottom to keep stress to the handlebar mount low.

But quality will suffer from putting it back together. The seal isn't perfect anymore and it could more easily pop out again.

**Replacements** are available from the manufacturer of the bike and probably also in auto stores because the part is also used for example for the self-leveling suspension adjustment of Mercedes 1999 E320 cars. The female parts unscrew from the rod, they are identical on both sides. The male parts should also unscrew. I'll add more details on replacing them once I do. Right now the reassembled one seems fine.

**Prevent** it from happening again:

- According to the manufacturer they should really never pop out like that, it's very unusual. Possibly the reason was that the handlebar mount was (slightly) out of alignment. It's important the ball part has a right angle with the rod or equivalently the flat part of the handlebar mount is parallel to the rod. The alignment in the picture is pretty good: [image: Illustration of previous paragraph.] The red lines are supposed to be parallel to the parts they are drawn on and have right angles.
- Setting the steering up to be less sensitive will improve steering behaviour in free handed (i.e. no hand at handlebars) pushing and make such an accident during pushing extremely unlikely. And while riding it pretty much can't happen in any circumstances anyway.
- An M6x50 bolt will fit nicely through the slit of that part next to the fork where the ball joint is mounted: [image: Fork mount with slit.] Put it in from below using a washers on both sides of the slit and a nut on top. Wrap the thread with insulation tape or any other rubbery tape or shrink wrap it (possibly several layers of shrink wrap) so it doesn't scratch the frame. It acts as a steering limiter. Mounted at the outermost point it limits the steering to the largest plausibly useful range.

Answer (score 7):

What you have there is a ball joint (sometimes called a tie rod end)  on a push rod (or track or tie rod) for indirect steering.

I'm astonished it could pop out that easily - Normally they're very secure.

Here's what a car one looks like when exploded.  Yours will be similar but much smaller and lighter.

[image: http://image.fourwheeler.com/f/47147002+w660+h440+q80+re0+cr1+ar0/154-1307-03%2Bheavy-duty-custom-steering-built-for-abuse%2Bball-joint-exploded-view]

I think you need a replacement ball joint. These are the same as ones used in car steering systems, and they are unserviceable. You generally cannot disassemble them without destroying the seal - all you can do is grease them via a grease nipple, if they have one.

The old parts should unscrew from the track rod end (there may be a clamp or retainer screw) and from the fork's arm. On a car, you use a Ball Joint Splitter to get the ball part out of the arm. The hole has sloped sides for an inference fit once tight, just like the sides of a square taper are sloped. In the exploded pic above, the slopey sided bit is clearly visible between the ball and the threadded part.  Yours will likely be too small for a car tool.

This is a Ball joint fork - hammered in.
[image]

And this is a ball joint separator which levers the ball out.
[image]